# SSRS Static Date Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm creating an SSRS report and I need to set a begin date so that it always returns 12/21/2015.  Is there an expression to use in SSRS to bring back a static date that will never change?

I've been chewing on this for awhile and searching everywhere.
Thanks

Comment: As a parameter, report expression of in sql server?

Comment: Make the date parameter default expression =CDate("12/21/2015")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SSRS you can produce date objects manually using [CDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx) and [DATESERIAL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/bbx05d0c(v=vs.90).aspx) functions.

To produce today date manually you can use:

`CDATE("2016-11-11") --> yyyy-MM-dd`
or 
`DATESERIAL(2016,11,11) --> year, month, day`

And you can use them in any SSRS expression, i.e:

```
=IIF(Today()=CDATE("2016-11-11"), some crazy expression, some crazy expression)
```

or

```
=IIF(Today()=DATESERIAL(2016,11,11), some crazy expression , some crazy expression)
```

Let me know if this helps.